# Vertical rule at the left of a listing

Tags: listings, rules

I would like to draw vertical rules *at a specific location* in the left margin of a listing in a `listings` environment. Is it possible ?

```
======= PSEUDO EXAMPLE =======

for i in range(5):
# One comment
    if i == 2:
# One comment
        print(i)

print("Finished....")

======= OUTPUT WISHED (this is ASCII art ! ) =======

   for i in range(5):
    # One comment
|      if i == 2:
|   # One comment
|          print(i)

    print("Finished....")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use TikZ and it’s overlay function …

Here’s my solution.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{%
        escapechar=§% or what fits to your code
    }
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \tikzstyle{every lst line}=[line width=3pt, gray]
    % command for setting a TikZ anchor
    \newcommand{\tanc}[1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \coordinate (#1) at (0,0);
%           \fill circle (0.5pt);% this line is for testing only
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    % some parameters
    \def\DeltaX{4cm}
    \def\DeltaYi{6pt}
    \def\DeltaYii{0pt}
    % command for drawing the lines
    \NewDocumentCommand{\makeline}{O{0pt} m m O{}}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, transform canvas={xshift=#1}]
            \draw [every lst line,#4] %
                let\p1=(#2), \p2=(#3), \p3=(current page.west) in%
                (\x3+\DeltaX,\y1+\DeltaYi) -- (\x3+\DeltaX,\y2+\DeltaYii);
            ;
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\usepackage{lipsum}% for testing

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{lstlisting}
for i in range(5):
# Pu§\tanc{one}§t the anchor somewhere in the line
if i == 2:
# One comment §\tanc{two}§
    print(i) §\tanc{three}§
print("Finished....")§\tanc{four}§
\end{lstlisting}
\makeline{one}{two}\makeline{three}{four}[red]
\makeline[-7pt]{one}{four}[blue]
%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Settings

- Choose an escape character that is never part of your listings. I choosed `§`.
- Adjust the `every lst line` style to fit your taste. This is the style applied to each line drawn with `\makeline`
- Adjust the parameters to fit you font and layout. `\DeltaX` = distance to left page border, `\DeltaYi` = shift between baseline of the anchored row in your listing an the start of the line and `\DeltaYii` same for second row.

### Usage

- Put an anchor somewhere in the row you want the line to start with `\tanc{<name 1>}`
  `# Pu§\tanc{one}§t the anchor somewhere in the line`
- Put a second anchor with `\tanc{<name 2>}`. The `names` should be unique at least for on listing.
  `print(i) §\tanc{two}§`
- Draw the line with `\makeline{<name 1>}{<name 2>}`.
  `\makeline{one}{two}`

  You may change the line style of the line using the second optional argument and shift the line horizontally using the first one:
  `\makeline[<x shift>]{<name 1>}{<name 2>}[<style>]`
  `\makeline[-7pt]{one}{four}[blue]`

  If you load a `decoration` library you can also add big curly braces or whatever by using the `<style>` argument.
- run LaTeX twice otherwise TikZ can’t get the right positions of the `remember picture` nodes.

### Result

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for this... I will start soon how to use TiKz for enhancing my documents.

Comment: @projetmbc: I improved my answer and extend the code. If you want to learn TikZ you may consider the pgfmanual containing some great tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the possibilty to indicate two lines, or more. That will help for producing documents to start programmation. PS : could you remove `\start{fold}` et `\end{fold}` in the example because they don't belong to the listing ?

Comment: @projetmbc I removed them. Don’t know why they where there … I also added a not that the example needs two latex runs

Comment: Indeed I've puted `\start{fold}` et `\end{fold}` to materialze where I wanted to place the LaTeX commands to draw the rules. This corresponds to your `§\tanc{...}§`.

Comment: @projetmbc Ahh … I see … :-)

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this code for my question on adding circled numbers (annotations) to listings: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51597/how-to-add-numerical-ala-no-starch-press-listing-notes-without-xetex It would be nice if you could check that one and see how it fits your code.

Comment: @soze: I’m sorry, but I didn’t understand what you want me to do … could you pleas explain what you’re expecting …?