# Position tikz pictures at left margin of a listing code block

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I'm trying to finish my attempt at having good looking unlimited line annotations for the listing environments, using tikz. The original problem was that indentation caused shifts in the positioning, so I changed the code to use the overlay feature.

My original question is here:
[How to add numerical (ala No Starch Press) listing notes without XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51597/how-to-add-numerical-ala-no-starch-press-listing-notes-without-xetex)

Unfortunately, I'm still unable to figure out how to properly align them:

**Update**: the code is merged with Werner's version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
\setmonofont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Mono Caps}]{Latin Modern Mono Light}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\oldstylenums{#1}}}

\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}

\newcommand*\lnnum[2][,]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base), overlay]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.8pt,
                    fill=black, text=white, #1] (char) {\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#2};}}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}\llap{{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}}\hskip 4em}}
\newcommand*{\linenum}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#1}%
  \lnnum[anchor=west]{#1}\hspace*{\dimexpr1ex+\wd0\relax}%
}
\lstnewenvironment{annotatedcsource}[1][]
{
    \setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}
        \lstset{
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            frame=lines,
            framexleftmargin=0.5em,
            framexrightmargin=0.5em,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            numberstyle=\normalsize\itshape\mynumold,
            backgroundcolor=\color{LemonChiffon1},
            showstringspaces=false,
            numbers=left,
            numbersep=2.5em,
            escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},#1}
        }
{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{annotatedcsource}[caption={RC4 blues}]
void
rc4_init(struct rc4_state *const state, const u_char *key, int keylen)
{
    u_char j;
    int i, k;

    /* Initialize state with identity permutation */
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        (*@\lnote@*)state->perm[i] = (u_char)i; 
    state->index1 = 0;
    (*@\lnote@*)state->index2 = 0;

    /* Randomize the permutation using key data */
    for (j = i = k = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        j += state->perm[i] + key[k]; 
        (*@\lnote@*)swap_bytes(&state->perm[i], &state->perm[j]);
        if (++k >= keylen)
            (*@\lnote@*)k = 0;
    }
\end{annotatedcsource}

Some source code doing whatever \linenum{1}, with line numbers and annotations \linenum{2}.

\begin{annotatedcsource}[caption={Hello blues}]
void hello(int times)
{
    int i;

    (*@\lnote@*)if (times > 4) {
        printf("Feeling chatty today?\n");
        return;
    }

    /* foobar */
    (*@\lnote@*)for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        printf("Hello %d!\n", i);
    }

    printf("Adios!\n");

    (*@\lnote@*)return;
}
\end{annotatedcsource}

Some source code doing whatever \linenum{1}, with line numbers and annotations \linenum{2}.

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: incorrectly aligned output makes soze a sad panda]

Desired output:

- Properly aligned circled numbers to the left or right margins along the line numbers.

  - In other words, the circled numbers must appear outside of the code block box, to the right or left of the line numbers.
- Any kind of source code listing should work fine, no indentation assumptions (please).
- Properly spaced circled numbers for the actual references embedded in the text.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Somehow I can't get XeTeX working so I used PFDLaTeX by adding `anchor=west,` option to the tikzpicture and using say `Some source code doing whatever \lnnum{1}\quad, with line numbers and annotations \lnnum{2}\quad.` solves the second problem. Frankly, I couldn't understand what your first problem is. Note that `snakes` library is deprecated and replaced with decorations.

Comment: percusse, I've clarified the desired output. It's the alignment and positioning of the circled numbers in the code block that bothers me. \quad seems like it should go into a new command defined for the references, to avoid duplicating the code. Re: snakes, correct, I took the minimal example template from an old file and forgot to remove it (obvious as there are no snake decorations anywhere).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following seems a bit of a hack, but provides the output you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
%\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
%\setromanfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
%\setmonofont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Mono Caps}]{Latin Modern Mono Light}
%\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
%\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

%\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}#1}}
\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\oldstylenums{#1}}}

\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}

\newcommand*\lnnum[2][,]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base), overlay]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.8pt,
                    fill=black, text=white, #1] (char) {\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#2};}}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}\llap{{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}}\hskip 4em}}
\newcommand*{\linenum}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#1}%
  \lnnum[anchor=west]{#1}\hspace*{\dimexpr1ex+\wd0\relax}%
}
\lstnewenvironment{annotatedcsource}[1][]
{
    \setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}
        \lstset{
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            frame=lines,
            framexleftmargin=0.5em,
            framexrightmargin=0.5em,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            numberstyle=\normalsize\itshape\mynumold,
            backgroundcolor=\color{LemonChiffon1},
            showstringspaces=false,
            numbers=left,
            numbersep=2.5em,
            escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},#1}
        }
{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{annotatedcsource}[caption={Foobar}]
void hello(int times)
{
    int i;

    (*@\lnote@*)if (times > 4) {
        printf("Feeling chatty today?\n");
        return;
    }

    /* foobar */
    (*@\lnote@*)for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        printf("Hello %d!\n", i);
    }

    printf("Adios!\n");

    (*@\lnote@*)return;
}
\end{annotatedcsource}

Some source code doing whatever \linenum{1}, with line numbers and annotations \linenum{2}.

\end{document}
```

`numbersep=2.5em` pushes the listing numbers `2.5em` away from the listing edge. As such, this leaves room to push `\lnote` a length `4em` from where it's called; into the gap. This is the hack I'm referring to: moving the TikZ node `4em` (a fixed length), since one may require a length that depends on the indentation of the listing. `\linenum{<num>}` now sets `\lnnum` with `anchor=west` and pads it with some horizontal space to properly align any following text.

---

An alternative version that sets the TikZ node in a "less-hacky" way. :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
%\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
%\setromanfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Linux  Libertine O}
%\setmonofont[SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Mono Caps}]{Latin Modern Mono Light}
%\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
%\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\let\insertnotenum\relax
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep\insertnotenum}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

%\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}#1}}
\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\oldstylenums{#1}}}

\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}

\newcommand*\lnnum[2][,]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base), overlay]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.8pt,
                    fill=black, text=white, #1] (char) {\normalfont\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#2};}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lnote}{%
  \stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}%
  \global\def\insertnotenum{\lnnum[anchor=east,xshift=-1.5ex]{\thelstNoteCounter}%
  \global\let\insertnotenum\relax}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\linenum}[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#1}%
  \lnnum[anchor=west]{#1}\hspace*{\dimexpr1ex+\wd0\relax}%
}
\lstnewenvironment{annotatedcsource}[1][]
{
    \setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}
        \lstset{
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            frame=lines,
            framexleftmargin=0.5em,
            framexrightmargin=0.5em,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            numberstyle=\normalsize\itshape\mynumold,
            backgroundcolor=\color{LemonChiffon1},
            showstringspaces=false,
            numbers=left,
            numbersep=2.5em,
            escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},#1}
        }
{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{annotatedcsource}[caption={Foobar}]
void hello(int times)(*@\lnote@*)
{
    int i;
    (*@\lnote@*)
    if (times > 4) {
        printf("Feeling chatty today?\n");
        return;
    }

    (*@\lnote@*)/* foobar */
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {(*@\lnote@*)
        printf("Hello %d!\n", i);
    }

    printf("Adios!\n");
    (*@\lnote@*)
    return;
}
\end{annotatedcsource}

Some source code doing whatever \linenum{1}, with line numbers and annotations \linenum{2}.

\end{document}
```

The modifications include:

1. A change in the way the `numbers` key-value is handled. The modification inserts `\insertnotenum` as part of the line number printing mechanism (or `\lst@PlaceNumber`);
2. `\insertnotenum` is a self-destruct macro that removes itself after it is used;
3. Use `(*@\lnote@*)` *before* the line that you want referenced, so that the line number of the *following* line is appropriately marked.

Note that this version now sets `\lnote` at the same horizontal distance, regardless of the code indentation.

Comment: They broke this for us! See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451532/recent-issues-with-lstlinebgrd-package-with-listings-after-the-latters-updates

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

%\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}#1}}
\newcommand{\mynumold}[1]{{\oldstylenums{#1}}}

\newcounter{lstNoteCounter}

\newcommand*\lnnum[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base), overlay]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.8pt,
                    fill=black, text=white, xshift=-4ex] (char) {\rmfamily\bfseries\footnotesize#1};}}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{\stepcounter{lstNoteCounter}\llap{{\lnnum{\thelstNoteCounter}}\hskip 3em}}

\lstnewenvironment{annotatedcsource}[1][]
{
    \setcounter{lstNoteCounter}{0}
        \lstset{
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            frame=lines,
            framexleftmargin=0.5em,
            framexrightmargin=0.5em,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            numberstyle=\normalsize\itshape\mynumold,
            backgroundcolor=\color{LemonChiffon1},
            showstringspaces=false,
            numbers=left,
            numbersep=8ex,
            escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},#1}
        }
{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{annotatedcsource}[caption={Foobar}]
void hello(int times)
{
    int i;

    (*@\lnote@*)if (times > 4) {
        printf("Feeling chatty today?\n");
        return;
    }

    /* foobar */
    (*@\lnote@*)for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        printf("Hello %d!\n", i);
    }

    printf("Adios!\n");

    (*@\lnote@*)return;
}
\end{annotatedcsource}

Some source code doing whatever \lnnum{1}, with line numbers and annotations \lnnum{2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The "trick" is to pass some `numbersep=` value to `listings` and use the `xshift=` option for the TikZ node.

(I have changed some packages in order to use pdflatex instead of xelatex, which I currently have not available. However, that should not be the point).

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Hm... seems that Werner basically had the same idea – and quick as he always is, he was about 3 Minutes earlier :-)

Comment: Werner is epic. Thank you both, I'm checking this. Bear with my tikz absolute rookie status, I bet this one was a tad stupid, but I also bet some people will appreciate the annotation hack for listings.