# Label inside a code listing

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

Does anybody know how to use labels inside a code listing that it looks something similarly like this:

[image: labels inside a code listening]

I know that it's easier to use the line number but I prefer using some labels.

Comment: Related: [Position `tikz` pictures at left margin of a listing code block](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51825/5764)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following example defines a new counter `llabel` for the listings' markings.
Package `pifont` is used to get the symbols, therefore the markings are limited to the range of 1 upto 10. Otherwise, package `tikz` can be used to draw own symbols without this limitation.

Macro `\llabel` takes a symbolic name that can be used later for `\ref`. It needs to be executed right at the beginning of the line, because then its position is known. The label is put to the left with the distance `\llabelsep` from the listings line number.
To get `\llabel` executed inside the listings the `mathescape` feature of package `listings` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % Counter `lstlisting' is not defined before `\begin{document}'
  \newcounter{llabel}[lstlisting]%
  \renewcommand*{\thellabel}{%
    \ifnum\value{llabel}<0 %
      \@ctrerr
    \else
      \ifnum\value{llabel}>10 %
        \@ctrerr
      \else
        \protect\ding{\the\numexpr\value{llabel}+201\relax}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\newlength{\llabelsep}
\setlength{\llabelsep}{5pt}

\newcommand*{\llabel}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{llabel}%
    \label{#1}%
    \llap{%
      \thellabel\kern\llabelsep
      \hphantom{\lst@numberstyle\the\lst@lineno}%
      \kern\lst@numbersep
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\subsection{Hello, world!}  
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language=C,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small\itshape,
  stepnumber=1,
  frame=lines,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!25},
  mathescape,
]   
$\llabel{header}$#include <stdio.h>

/* This is a comment */
$\llabel{main}$int main()
{
$\llabel{hello}$    printf("Hello, world!\n");
$\llabel{exit}$    return 0;
}

/* Another function */
$\llabel{foobar}$int foobar()
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
We first include the \verb|stdio.h| header file \ref{header}.
We then declare the \verb|main| function \ref{main}.
We then print ``Hello, world!'' \ref{hello}.
Finally, we return value 0 \ref{exit}.
Another function \verb|foobar| is defined in \ref{foobar}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

It is also possible to have source files that keep working by using special markers
and using option

escapeinside={/*@}{@*/}

instead of `mathescape`:

```c
/*@\llabel{header}@*/#include <stdio.h>

/* This is a comment */
/*@\llabel{main}@*/int main()
{
/*@\llabel{hello}@*/    printf("Hello, world!\n");
/*@\llabel{exit}@*/    return 0;
}

/* Another function */
/*@\llabel{foobar}@*/int foobar()
{
    return 0;
}
```

### Putting `\llabel` at end of line

The following variant allows to put `\llabel` anywhere on the source line, also the end of line, where it does not disrupt the formatting. For this purpose the line marker is also remembered by a label with the line number in its name. The marker is then put along the line number hooking into `numberstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % Counter `lstlisting' is not defined before `\begin{document}'
  \newcounter{llabel}[lstlisting]%
  \renewcommand*{\thellabel}{%
    \ifnum\value{llabel}<0 %  
      \@ctrerr
    \else
      \ifnum\value{llabel}>10 %
        \@ctrerr
      \else
        \protect\ding{\the\numexpr\value{llabel}+201\relax}%
      \fi
    \fi  
  }%   
}   
\newlength{\llabelsep}
\setlength{\llabelsep}{5pt}

\newcommand*{\llabel@name}{%
  llabel\the\value{lstlisting}.\the\lst@lineno
}
\newcommand*{\llabel}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{llabel}%
    \label{#1}%
    \label{\llabel@name}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\llabelput}{%
  \@ifundefined{r@\llabel@name}{%
  }{%
    \ref{\llabel@name}%
    \kern\llabelsep
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\subsection{Hello, world!}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language=C,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small\itshape\llabelput,
  stepnumber=1,
  frame=lines,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!25},
  columns=flexible,
  escapeinside={/*@}{@*/},
]
#include <stdio.h> /*@\llabel{header}@*/

/* This is a comment */
int main() /*@\llabel{main}@*/
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n"); /*@\llabel{hello}@*/
    return 0; /*@\llabel{exit}@*/
}

/* Another function */
int foobar() /*@\llabel{foobar}@*/
{
    return 0;
}   
\end{lstlisting}
We first include the \verb|stdio.h| header file \ref{header}.
We then declare the \verb|main| function \ref{main}.
We then print ``Hello, world!'' \ref{hello}.
Finally, we return value 0 \ref{exit}.
Another function \verb|foobar| is defined in \ref{foobar}.
\end{document}
```

This should also work with an external file instead of the embedded listings.

Comment: is it also possible to use label if the code is stored external in a *.cpp file?

Comment: Awesome. Referencing works fine but the llabel doesn't show up in the lstlisting.

Comment: @ei.schinken The markers in the listing of the latest variant is based on the output of the line number: no markers without line numbers.

Comment: Now it works properly except of the fact that it produces two reference labels if I'm using it on a line of code after an empty line of code.

Comment: @ei.schinken The latter variant that allows the comment with the `\llabel` in the middle or end of the line needs two `\label`, the second internal `\label` is used to get a relation between the marker and the line number.