# Lstlistings reference to line number

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, labels

How can I place a 'label' marker inside a lstlisting environment (external file imported and formatted via the listinputlisting command) so that I can cross-reference a particular line number?

In other words, I would like to be able to use the following sort of text content in my document.

> "By referring to line **LINE_NUMBER**, in listing ABC, the use of DEF
>   object has resulted in GHI objectives being met" etc...

Where the **LINE_NUMBER** would be marked in the file to the effect of `\label{line:marker}` and then used in the document with `\ref{line:marker}`.

It may require the use of an encapsulating flag/s, such as `<\label{line:marker}>` to differentiate from surrounding actual code, which is fine with me.

Cheers.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Label inside a code listing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85538/5764); [Referring to a whole line of code instead of a line number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123644/5764)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `escapechar=<char>` to use commands.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    language=Java,escapechar=|] %language and your escape char
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world !");|\label{line:sp}|   %% <--- label here
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

By referring to line~\ref{line:sp}, in listing ABC, the use of DEF object has resulted in GHI objectives being met" etc...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the escape char $ does not work if this is for labels.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer you can use `$`, but TEX’s special characters must be entered with a preceding backslash, e.g. `escapechar=\$`. See the [`listings` package manual, page 42](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)