# How to insert equation numbers with lstlisting?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, listings

I am trying to use the `lstlisting` environment to insert R code into my LaTeX document. What I cannot figure out is how to get LaTeX to number these equations so that I can refer back to them later in the text. I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133)
\end{lstlisting}\label{eq:lm.model}
```

To be clear -- I know I can do this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R, caption={Standard Linear Regression Model Equation}, label=foobar]
lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133)
\end{lstlisting}
```

However, I want to put the equation number to the right of the equation -- not in a separate header at top, and I want to be able to refer to it later in the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lstlistings reference to line number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144170/lstlistings-reference-to-line-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to create an R-listing (or actually any listing) inside `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`, you'll need to use `\lstinline` instead of  `\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}`. To start and end the code snippet, you can use any character which is *not* used within the code. A popular choice is e.g. `|` or `$`:

```
\lstinline[language=R]|lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133)|
```

but again, it doesn't matter as long as that character does not appear in your code snippet.

To be able to place this `\lstinline` within an equation, you have to "escape" math mode first, so you are in the "normal" text mode. This is done with `\text{any content which is not math}`. So together, this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
As described in \eqref{eq:lm.eq:lm.model}, this is very important.
\begin{equation} \label{eq:lm.eq:lm.model}
    \text{\lstinline[language=R]|lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133)|}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Typically references to listings are done either to the listing as a whole (and therefore would have a caption) or to the line numbers within the listing.

Below I follow the second approach as it seems strange to provide a single-line listing with a caption. Even though the numbering is set on the `left`, you can also place it on the `right`. See section **5.6 Line numbers** of the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more options regarding the formatting of line numbers inside a listing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{rcode}[1][]
  {\lstset{
     language=R,
     numbers=left,
     numberstyle=\footnotesize,
     escapeinside=@@,
     #1}}
  {}
\newsavebox{\codebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{rcode}
lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133) @\label{r:lm.model-1}@
\end{rcode}

See Line~\ref{r:lm.model-1} or Line~\ref{r:lm.model-2}.

\begin{rcode}[firstnumber=200]
lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133) @\label{r:lm.model-2}@
\end{rcode}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

Alternatively, see~(\ref{eq:lm.model-1}):
\begin{equation}
  \usebox{\codebox} \label{eq:lm.model-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
\lstinline[language=R]|lm.model <- lm(Total.Score ~ Game.Num, data = sid1133)|
\end{lrbox}

Alternatively, see~(\ref{eq:lm.model-2}):
\begin{equation}
  \usebox{\codebox} \label{eq:lm.model-2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In order to properly reference the line numbers, you'll have to *escape* to insert an appropriate `\label`.

If you really wish to include the listing code as an equation, you may want to consider storing the listing in a box before setting it (above I use `\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}` ... `\end{lrbox}`). Note the difference between the way content is set under the `lstlisting` *environment* and `\lstinline` *macro*.

Answer (score 0):

This example is best

```
\begin{equation}
\hbox{
\begin{lstlisting}
  @@
  (?:
   (?<commandOrEnvironmentName>[a-zA-Z]+)
   (?:@(?<groupingData>[,0-9\x20]+))?
  )?
  @@
   (?<PLSQLexpresion>.+?)
  @END@
   (?<endlineChars>.*?\n|.*)
\end{lstlisting}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add a few sentences to explain what your code does and how it addresses the OP's question.